# can you give me this hadith about the number prayers

Tags: salat, hadith

https://youtu.be/RsYFIKzkCpc?t=53

this cheikh said there is a hadith from Aicha saying " in the early days of islam there was 3 prayers and then it s expanded to 5( 3  remained just for travellers )

I want to find this specific hadith do you have any source ?

thanks you

Comment: Salam and welcome to ISlamSE the Q&a Site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. I saw a hadith like that in some of the answers on the site it is certainly quoted in imam Ahmad's Musnad and elsewhere. Maybe even in one of my own answers there's a link. The wording you use is too vague to clearly identify which hadith you exactly mean. The hadith is referring to prayer in early days of Islam. The wording I know of is about the amount of raka'as not of prayers.

Comment: Sorry I cant give you more info ,just watch 10s of the video link, I linked the exact moment the cheikh describe this hadith,Can you give me the hadith about raka'a anyway maybe it s this one thanks